# Hugging Face K-fold

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, confusion-matrix

I want to calculate confusion matrix with K-fold for the entire Hugging Face BERT model.

The question is whenever I calculate confusion matrix without K-fold it gives me larger numbers like this:
{'tn': 75, 'fp': 30, 'fn': 36, 'tp': 77}

but if I add K-fold it will give me this result:
{'tn': 44, 'fp': 1, 'fn': 1, 'tp': 39}.

am I doing something wrong or the results are correct?

Here is the code for calculating confusion matrix with K-fold:

```
confusion_matrices = []

for eval_result in eval_results:
    confusion_matrices.append(eval_result["eval_confusion_matrix"])

total_confusion_matrix = {'tn': 0, 'fp': 0, 'fn': 0, 'tp': 0}

for confusion_matrix in confusion_matrices:
    total_confusion_matrix['tn'] += confusion_matrix['tn']
    total_confusion_matrix['fp'] += confusion_matrix['fp']
    total_confusion_matrix['fn'] += confusion_matrix['fn']
    total_confusion_matrix['tp'] += confusion_matrix['tp']

num_folds = len(confusion_matrices)
avg_confusion_matrix = {
    'tn': total_confusion_matrix['tn'] // num_folds,
    'fp': total_confusion_matrix['fp'] // num_folds,
    'fn': total_confusion_matrix['fn'] // num_folds,
    'tp': total_confusion_matrix['tp'] // num_folds
}

print("Confusion matrix:", avg_confusion_matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your results look different because:

1. Without K-fold, you're testing on the whole dataset. With K-fold, you're testing on just a slice of it each time.
   Make sure your data is shuffled well. If classes aren't balanced, try Stratified K-Fold.
2. Your K-fold code is averaging results from each fold. This can give different numbers compared to a single run.
3. Your K-fold results might be correct, but always check your data shuffling and consider balancing the classes in each fold.

Your K-fold results might be correct, but always check your data shuffling and consider balancing the classes in each fold.

I hope this helps!